Jenkins fails to decrypt repository which has signing certificates iOS
Some signing certs expired last week whuch causes jenkins to fail uploading builds to firebase and appstore
We use Fastlane to manage our builds and deployments.
We have our certificates repo on Bitbucket.
In the certificates repo on Bitbucket there are branch for all the builds including an enterprise branch with a cert, p12 and provisioning file. These seems to be static and have been there since they were created. (Were they created via Fastlane CLI then or were they created manually and somehow imported to the repo).
I tried going on the Apple Developer account and creating the mobile provisioning manually and I replaced the one that was on the repo. But that caused an error:
Wrong final block length
couldn't decrypt the repo, please make sure you enter the right password!
invalid password passed via "MATCH_PASSWORD"
I tried going on the Apple Developer account and creating the mobile provisioning manually and I replaced the one that was on the repo. But that caused an error:
I have tried encrypting the p12 file and rerun the job to see if it works. it failed. I have encrypted file usning openssl
I am expecting how to fix this. How to decrypt repo url.
